# Sorting a list of names by greatest lexicographical order

Tags: python, performance, sorting, python-2.x

This is a puzzle I found online that I have been trying to optimize and make the best version. I've tested it and it works great but I'm curious how it can be improved in any way.

**Instructions**:

> "You forgot to give Professor Boolean's favorite rabbit specimen a
>   name? You know how picky the professor is! Only particular names will
>   do! Fix this immediately, before you're... eliminated!"
>
> Luckily, your minion friend has already come up with a list of
>   possible names, and we all know that the professor has always had a
>   thing for names with lots of letters near the 'tail end' of the
>   alphabet, so to speak. You realize that if you assign the value 1 to
>   the letter A, 2 to B, and so on up to 26 for Z, and add up the values
>   for all of the letters, the names with the highest total values will
>   be the professor's favorites. For example, the name Annie has value 1
>   + 14 + 14 + 9 + 5 = 43, while the name Earz, though shorter, has value 5 + 1 + 18 + 26 = 50.
>
> If two names have the same value, Professor Boolean prefers the
>   lexicographically larger name. For example, if the names were AL
>   (value 13) and CJ (value 13), he prefers CJ.
>
> Write a function answer(names) which takes a list of names and returns
>   the list sorted in descending order of how much the professor likes
>   them.
>
> There will be at least 1 and no more than 1000 names.  Each name will
>   consist only of lower case letters. The length of each name will be at
>   least 1 and no more than 8.
>
> Test cases:
>
> Inputs:
>
> ```
> (string list) names = ["annie", "bonnie", "liz"]
> ```
>
> Output:
>
> ```
> (string list) ["bonnie", "liz", "annie"]
> ```
>
> Inputs:
>
> ```
> (string list) names = ["abcdefg", "vi"]
> ```
>
> Output:
>
> ```
> (string list) ["vi", "abcdefg"]
> ```
>
> Your code will run inside a Python 2.7.6 sandbox.
>
> Standard libraries are supported except for `bz2`, `crypt`, `fcntl`, `mmap`,
>   `pwd`, `pyexpat`, `select`, `signal`, `termios`, `thread`, `time`, `unicodedata`,
>   `zipimport`, `zlib`.

My answer:

```
def answer(names):
    # Sort names by reverse alphebetical order
    names = sorted(names, reverse=True)
    # Evaluate the value of each name and build a list with name,value pairs
    name_with_values = sorted([((current_name,value(current_name))) for current_name in names], 
        key=lambda value: value[1], reverse=True)
    # Return the list only containing the names
    return [name[0] for name in name_with_values]

def value(name):
    # Evaluate and return value of the name
    return sum([ord(letter) - 96 for letter in name])

print answer(names = ["annie", "bonnie", "liz", "bpnnid"])
```

Feedback I'm interested in:

- Is my logic easy to understand?
- How can it be styled or named better?
- Is it more complex or more computationally expensive than it needs to be?
- How is the general readability/clarity?

Comment: Can you tell us where you found this puzzle? Is it a Google Foobar challenge?

Comment: Yeah, this is a Foobar challenge.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are using the [`sorted` function](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#sorted)'s `key` parameter in a very odd way. As you have a function that takes a string and returns a value to sort on, you could implement this much more neatly as:

```
def answer(names):
    return sorted(names, key=value, reverse=True)
```

See [this Python wiki article](https://wiki.python.org/moin/HowTo/Sorting/) for more on sorting. In use:

```
>>> sorted(["annie", "bonnie", "liz"], key=value, reverse=True)
['bonnie', 'liz', 'annie']
>>> sorted(["abcdefg", "vi"], key=value, reverse=True)
['vi', 'abcdefg']
```

Note that this doesn't meet the requirements for breaking ties, though; as `value('al') == value('cj')` and `sorted` is **stable**, they stay in the input order:

```
>>> sorted(('cj', 'al'), key=value, reverse=True)
['cj', 'al']  # ok!
>>> sorted(('al', 'cj'), key=value, reverse=True)
['al', 'cj']  # oh...
```

Your current pre-sort fixes this, and could be incorporated here too:

```
>>> sorted(sorted(('al', 'cj'), reverse=True), key=value, reverse=True)
['cj', 'al']
```

To get around this *without* overcomplicating the code, `value` can return a tuple `(score, string)`, so the `string` is used to break ties:

```
def value(name):
    """Evaluate and return value of the name."""
    return sum([ord(letter) - 96 for letter in name]), name
                                                   # ^ note
```

Now `'cj'` is always preferred:

```
>>> sorted(('al', 'cj'), key=value, reverse=True)
['cj', 'al']
>>> sorted(('cj', 'al'), key=value, reverse=True)
['cj', 'al']
```

---

Beyond that, note that you should use [docstrings](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0257/) rather than just comments:

```
def value(name):
    """Evaluate and return value of the name."""
    return sum([ord(letter) - 96 for letter in name])
```

Otherwise it looks pretty good: the code is well laid out, and follows the style guide. If anything, I'd say you have *too many* comments; they shouldn't explain things the reader could learn from the code, but *why* the code is written that way (if this is obvious, no comment is needed).